# Are compound statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?

Tags: c, gcc, standards, expression

Browsing the Linux kernel sources I found [some piece of code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L332) where a block of statements surrounded by parenthesis is treated as a expression *a la lisp* (or ML), that is, an expression which value is the value of the last statement.

For example:

```
int a = ({
    int i;
    int t = 1;
    for (i = 2; i<5; i++) {
        t*=i;
    }
    t;
});
```

I've been looking at the [ANSI C grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#assignment-expression) trying to figure out how this piece of code would fit in the parse tree, but I haven't been successful.

So, does anybody know if this behaviour is mandated by the standard or is just a peculiarity of GCC?

**Update:** I've tried with the flag -pedantic and the compiler now gives me a warning:

```
warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's called "braced-group within expression".

It's not allowed by ANSI/ISO C nor C++ but gcc supports it.

Comment: You can suppress the warning in GCC by putting `__extension__` before the opening parenthesis.

Comment: @Flimm why isn't that an answer?

Comment: `__extension__` helps, but NOT when the statement is used at the global scope

Comment: @hellow: Because it doesn't solve the problem; it just wall-papers over it.

Answer (score 43):

This is not standard C. It is a gcc extension called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). You can find the complete list of C extensions [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions). This is actually one of the [many gcc extensions used in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gcc-hacks/) and it seems like [clang supports this too](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#gcc-extensions-not-implemented-yet) and although it is not explicitly named in the document.

As you observed the last expression serves as the value of the expression, the document says (*emphasis mine*):

> The **last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct**. (If you use some other kind of statement last within the braces, the construct has type void, and thus effectively no value.)

One of the main benefits would be to make *safe* macros that would avoid multiple evaluations of arguments with side effects. The example given uses this unsafe macro:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

which evaluates either `a` or `b` twice and can be rewritten to eliminate this problem using statement expressions as follows:

```
#define maxint(a,b) \
   ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Note, the need to explicitly use `int` which can fixed using another `gcc` extension [Typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof):

```
#define max(a,b) \
   ({ typeof (a) _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Note that [clang also supports typeof](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes).

Comment: Is it possible to write a macro to be safe like that without statement expressions?

Comment: @Flimm I don't think so but I would not consider myself a macro expert. I avoid them as much as I can, although there are some cases they are hard to avoid such as rolling your own assert.

Comment: @Flimm That depends on what you want your macro to do, in some cases it's certainly possible to write a safe macro. For the complete `max` functionality you'll fall short in someway no matter what you do in standard C - the problem is that you either need to know the type of the arguments or you have to evaluate one of them twice (of which the later is the problem with the macro approach above).

Comment: Hmpf, the last one should be modified to properly support heterogenous arguments.