# C block becomes expression: ( {int a = 1; int b = 2; a+b;} ) equals 3

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

While reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Multiple_evaluation_of_side_effects, I came across this example:

```
\#define max(a,b) \
   ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
       typeof (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; }) // WHY DOES THIS LINE WORK?
```

Which you can use exactly like a function, i.e. `max(1,2)` is an expression evaluating to 2.

My QUESTION is, *How does `({ statment-list last-expression; })` construct evaluate to the value of last-expression?* Specifically, what does a parse tree of this construct look like? I thought `{ }` always meant a compound-statement, and statements have no values. I tried digging around in the **C** grammar and still couldn't figure this problem out.

Comment: `42;` is a statement as well :-)

Comment: Ah, but I suspect the OP knows that `42;` is a statement because it is a statement in Standard C. The statement expression is not in Standard C, however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are compound statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compound-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a GCC extension called [Statement Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). It's not standard C.

Comment: Statement expressions?! Sounds like a headache.

Comment: Thanks! Of course I should have actually read "both the typeof keyword, and the construct of placing a compound statement within parentheses, are non-standard extensions implemented in the popular GNU C compiler (GCC)." Oops.

Comment: I like them. They allow to do intelligent stuff like this. :)