# Explanation of C++ FAQ's unsafe macro?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

[According to the C++ FAQ, macros are evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-vs-macros.html):

> [9.5] Why should I use inline functions instead of plain old #define
>   macros?
>
> Because `#define` macros are evil in 4 different ways: evil#1, evil#2,
>   evil#3, and evil#4. Sometimes you should use them anyway, but they're
>   still evil.
>        Unlike `#define` macros, inline functions avoid infamous macro errors since inline functions always evaluate every argument exactly
>   once. In other words, invoking an inline function is semantically just
>   like invoking a regular function, only faster:
>
> ```
> // A macro that returns the absolute value of i
> #define unsafe(i)  \
>         ( (i) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i) )
>
> // An inline function that returns the absolute value of i
> inline
> int safe(int i)
> {
>   return i >= 0 ? i : -i;
> }
>
> int f();
>
> void userCode(int x)
> {
>   int ans;
>
>   ans = unsafe(x++);   // Error! x is incremented twice
>   ans = unsafe(f());   // Danger! f() is called twice
>
>   ans = safe(x++);     // Correct! x is incremented once
>   ans = safe(f());     // Correct! f() is called once
> }
> ```
>
> Also unlike macros, argument types are checked, and necessary
>   conversions are performed correctly.
>
> Macros are bad for your health; don't use them unless you have to.

Can someone explain why is `unsafe(x++)` increments `x` twice? I am not able to figure out.

Comment: First time in the condition, 2nd time in the branches of the ternary operator.

Comment: Macros are *not* bad. If one doesn't understand a language construct and misuses (abuses) then almost every language construct can come under "..... is evil" category.

Comment: macros is as evil as goto. If you do not understand, dont use it, if you do understand, that it is very very useful.

Comment: To expand on Jonatan Goebel's thought: macros can be dangerous and confusing, but they have their place. Don't use a macro to do something that you can achieve simply in a less dangerous and confusing way.

Comment: @KingsIndian, macros are evil if only because their effects aren't bounded reasonably. Unintended consequences are far too easy to cause and can't always be predicted, even when you're careful. For example if you have a class with a `GetText` function, be careful when you use it in a Windows program - Microsoft does `#define GetText GetTextW` which might cause a mismatch if you link against a library that doesn't use Windows.

Comment: Agreeing with @Jonatan, I get really frosted by this judgementalism that assumes programmers are stupid. I don't mind mentioning what the pitfalls are, but this business of calling things evil is just adolescent nonsense.

Comment: Macros do indeed have their place in C, when used carefully, but... C macros _are_ about as awful as a macro system can possibly be, and still be called a macro system. Just because some people overstate the case against ('evil' is a bit strong), doesn't mean the case _for_ C macros should be advanced with anything resembling enthusiasm.

Comment: C macros are not evil. They should be used for boilerplate code generation which otherwise would be unreadable and unmaintainable. But of course they should not be used in place of inline functions and such. My favourite example of the idiomatic macros use is .inc and .def files in LLVM and Clang.

Comment: Actually, in almost every case, templates should be used for boilerplate code generation--not macros. Macros are really only good for syntactically strange things that can't be represented as a normal function.

Comment: I was once shown a nearly complete implementation of C++ V1.0 done completely with macros on a C compiler. That was definitely `EVIL`, in the sense of being dangerous to the uninitiated, and fragile.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel and perhaps you can show us a case where gotos are actually useful? Pointless generalizations are pointless. Perhaps you should read Dijkstra's paper which describes *why* gotos are best avoided. Gotos are considered harmful because they serve no useful purpose, they let us do nothing that can't be done in other, safer and more convenient ways in today's programming languages. And inevitably, newbies go "oh, but it can't be all that bad, I'm sure they have their uses", and no, unless you're working in C, I know of no situation where a goto is the best tool for the job

Comment: Which, incidentally, is very different from macros. Macros are tricky to use correctly, and really should be avoided wherever possible, but they do have their uses. There are things you can do with macros that would not otherwise be possible. Equating the two shows a frightening degree of ignorance.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, no, templates cannot be used for boilerplate code generation in cases I've mentioned: e.g., list of enums, for which you have to generate case statements in a variety of contexts and a type definition. Something like this cannot be done by the too limited C++ templates, but is pretty safe and straightforward with macros.

Comment: @jalf, gotos are *extremely* useful and any language without goto support is quite handicap. You cannot implement a proper state machine without goto, because state transition is, *surprise*, semantically equivalent to goto, not to a `case` in a `switch` or anything else equally pathetic. You cannot implement high level optimisations for your [e]DSL compiler if your target language does not support goto. Goto haters are so brainwashed!

Comment: all the people who have implemented state machines without gotos are going to be *extremely* surprised to hear that.

Comment: @jalf, I said "*proper*" state machine, not a stupid leaky abstraction with switch or array of function pointers. Take a look at Knuth's `adventure` for example.

Comment: And I say, once again, all the people who have done just that are going to be very surprised. I'll also say that many people who have used gotos for this are going to be quite surprised that it is apparently no longer a leaky abstraction. That it just works and won't in any way come back to bite you. (And, quite impressively, that the ultimate proof is in a code sample from 1975)

Comment: @jalf, Knuth's code is still a right way to go (and it had been published long after Dijkstra's funny rant). And yes, goto is not a leaky abstraction in this case - it's exactly the problem domain semantics as it is. Goto is ultimately a state transition. Anything else is just a pathetic simulation of it. And it's funny that you ignored a much more important use of `goto` I've mentioned - in the generated optimised code. E.g., a parser generated out of a declarative high level definition.

Comment: P.S., for a more modern (but much less elegant) example of code, just do `grep -r goto` inside Linux kernel source tree. You'll be surprised.

Comment: not leaky? You do know there are quite a few limitations to how and where you can use gotos, and what happens to variables whose lifetimes span across labels, yes (especially with non-POD types)? I did ignore the optimization part, yes, because I'm talking about code you write yourself. Gotos in generated code is a different matter (because readability and maintainability isn't a concern, and in this sense it's just another name for a jump instruction).

Comment: Anyway, until one of us is willing to take the time to implement the same code with and without gotos so we can make an actual apples to apples comparison, this is a waste of time.

Comment: @jalf, code you write yourself will write the generated code. In the same language. And if this language is such a pathetic crap that it does not even support goto, then your optimisation options are limited and code generation is much more complicated then necessary. As for "limitations", remember, each state processing is isolated (no need to worry about variables life span). Again, read Knuth's code.

Comment: @jalf, nobody is ever going to even try to re-write Linux or LLVM or whatever else without goto. Because goto is nice and readable, and without goto the same code looks like crap. Which simply proves my point: gotos are necessary in any imperative language, and those who do not use them because of some stupid religion are missing many of the opportunities and are incapable of writing and maintaining clean and efficient code. Dixi.

Comment: If `goto` was that evil, why would Microsoft have implemented it in their C# compiler?

Comment: Why the hell are we having the same argument we've had a thousand times already? macros, `goto`, whatever. Do any of you think you're saying anything new?  The question was simply asking why `unsafe(x++)` is problematic. I really think most of you should just delete your comments.

(I guess I'm not being very novel here either!)

Comment: `++` is evil because it can cause undefined behaviour. E.g. `int x = INT_MAX; x++; /* <-- undefined behaviour */`. "evil" is overused in this context. Just explain the pitfalls and explain the potential problems in a factual way.

Comment: Part of the [rationale for statement expressions, which is an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18885626/1708801) was safe macros.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Running it through the preprocessor shows the problem. Using `gcc -E` (can also use `cpp -P`, where the `-P` option also suppresses generated `#` lines),

```
inline
int safe(int i)
{
  return i >= 0 ? i : -i;
}

int f();

void userCode(int x)
{
  int ans;

  //    increment 1      increment 2 (one of these)
  //        |             |     |
  //        V             V     V
  ans = ( (x++) >= 0 ? (x++) : -(x++) );
  ans = ( (f()) >= 0 ? (f()) : -(f()) );

  ans = safe(x++);
  ans = safe(f());
}
```

As artless noise notes, the function `f()` is also called twice by the `unsafe` macro. Perhaps it's *pure* (has no side-effects) so it's not *wrong*, per se. But still suboptimal.

So, since inline functions are generally safer than function-like macros because they work on the same semantic level with the other basic elements: variables and expressions; and for manifest constants, `enum`s can often be more *tidy*; **what are the *good* uses of macros?**

**Setting constants known only at compile-time.** You can define a macro from the command-line when compiling. Instead of

```
#define X 12
```

in the source file, you can add

```
-DX=12
```

to the `cc` command. You can also `#undef X` from the command-line with `-UX`.

This allows things like conditional-compilation, eg.

```
#if X
   do this;
#else
   do that;
#endif
   while (loop);
```

to be controlled by a makefile, itself perhaps generated with a configure script.

**X-Macros**. The most compelling use for X-Macros, IMO, is associating `enum` identifiers with printable strings. While it make look funny at first, it reduces duplication and synchronization issues with these kinds of parallel definitions.

```
#define NAMES(_) _(Alice) _(Bob) _(Caravaggio) _(DuncanIdaho)
#define BARE(_) _ ,
#define STRG(_) #_ ,
enum { NAMES(BARE) };
char *names[] = { NAMES(STRG) };
```

Notice that you can pass a macro's name as an argument to another macro and then call the passed macro by using the argument *as if* it were itself a macro (because it *is* one). For more on X-Macros, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6635851/733077).

Comment: ... and, as we all know it, that is an UB!

Comment: What, specifically, is undefined @BЈовић

Comment: @Koushik correct - there is a sequence point at the `?` (i.e. after the evaluation of the condition) but before the execution of one of the two branches.

Comment: You could highlight the duplicate function calls as well.  Even if they are *pure*, they are a waste of time.

Comment: Here's a 'once-only' macro that solves this problem for common lisp: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html  . Doug Hoyte also has a version: http://letoverlambda.com/textmode.cl/guest/chap3.html#sec_6

Answer (score 17):

Macros effectively do a copy/paste *before* the program is compiled.

```
unsafe(x++)
```

Would become

```
( (x++) >= 0 ? (x++) : -(x++) )
```

Comment: I would probably describe it more as a find/replace all (with a couple more rules than a basic text search).

Answer (score 10):

The preprocessor replaces the macro before compilation.

The compiler sees this:

```
  ( (x++) >= 0 ? (x++) : -(x++) )
```

Answer (score 4):

`unsafe(x)` evaluates the expression `x` twice. Once to determine its truth value, and then a second time in one of the two branches of the ternary operator. The inline function `safe` receives an evaluated argument: the expression is evaluated once prior to the function call, and the function call works with local variables.

> `unsafe` is actually not quite as unsafe as it could be. The ternary operator introduces a sequence point between evaluating the test, and evaluating either the consequent or alternative expression. `unsafe(x++)` will *reliably* increments `x` twice, though, of course, the problem is that this behavior is unexpected. In general, macros which expand an expression more than once do not have this assurance. Usually, they produce outright undefined behavior!

Circa 1999 I produced a library module module for catching uses of macros with side effects.

So, you can write "evil" macros and use them, and the machine will catch situations where they are accidentally used with arguments that have side effects (provided you have adequate code coverage to hit those uses at run-time).

Here is the test program, `unsafe.c`. Note that it includes a header file `sfx.h` and uses a `SFX_CHECK` macro in the expansion token sequence of `unsafe`:

```
#include "sfx.h"

#define unsafe(i)  \
          ( (SFX_CHECK(i)) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i) )

inline
int safe(int i)
{
  return i >= 0 ? i : -i;
}

int f(void)
{
  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  int ans;
  int x = 0;

  ans = unsafe(x++);   // Error! x is incremented twice
  ans = unsafe(f());   // Danger! f() is called twice

  ans = safe(x++);     // Correct! x is incremented once
  ans = safe(f());     // Correct! f() is called once
}
```

We compile everything and run from a Linux shell prompt:

```
$ gcc unsafe.c hash.c except.c sfx.c -o unsafe
$ ./unsafe
unsafe.c:22: expression "x++" has side effects
unsafe.c:23: expression "f()" may have side effects
```

Note that `x++` certainly has side effects, whereas `f` may or may not. So the messages are differently worded. A function being called twice is not necessarily an issue, because a function might be *pure* (have no side effects).

You can get that [here](http://www.kylheku.com/~kaz/kazlib.html) if you're curious about how it works. There is a run-time penalty if the debugging is enabled; of course `SFX_CHECK` can be disabled so it does nothing (similarly to `assert`).

The first time an `SFX_CHECK` protected expression is evaluated, it is parsed in order to determine whether it might have side effects. Because this parsing is done without any access to symbol table information (how identifiers are declared), it is ambiguous. The parser pursues multiple parsing strategies. Backtracking is done using an exception-handling library based on `setjmp/longjmp`.  The parse results are stored in a hash table keyed on the textual expression for faster retrieval on future evaluations.