# What is argument evaluation?

Tags: c

Herbert Schildt says:

> In some situations, real function should be used in place of function-like-macro, for example: where code size is to be minimized or where an argument must not be evaluated more than once.

What does he mean by *"an argument must not be evaluated more than once?"*

Comment: Schildt is [seen sceptical by some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Schildt#Reception). Just sayin'.

Comment: @DevSolar: I don't know that book, but if the cited statement is typical for the style, I fully agree with the sceptics.

Comment: @DevSolar You meant [skeptical](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Askeptical), right? Or did you spell it with a [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) because this question is tagged [tag:c] and not [tag:k]? :P

Comment: @tac [It's only "skeptical" in the USA's variant of the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Hard_and_soft_.22c.22)

Comment: Regardless of which side of the pond you inhabit, it's being used as an adverb in that sentence, so it should be sceptically/skeptically.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043090/why-should-i-avoid-macros-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243509/explanation-of-c-faqs-unsafe-macro (not actually duplicates, since this question is tagged C, but the problems are nearly identical in both languages)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Let's take a macro to calculate the maximum of two values:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Then we use it like this:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
int max = MAX(x++, y++);
```

Then the macro is expanded to

```
int max = ((x++) < (y++) ? (x++) : (y++));
```

As you can see, the increment operation on either `x` or `y` will happen *twice*, not what would happen if you had a function where each argument you pass is evaluated only once.

---

Another important point is the use of parentheses in the macro. Let's take another simple macro:

```
#define MUL(a, b) a * b
```

Now if you invoke the macro as

```
int sum = MUL(x + 3, y - 2);
```

then the expansion becomes

```
int sum = x + 3 * y - 2;
```

Which due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is equal to

```
int sum = x + (3 * y) - 2;
```

Often not quite what was expected, if one expects `(x + 3) * (y - 2)`.

This problem is also "solved" by using functions.

Comment: I think what you said is opposite.  For the function call `max(x, x++)`, `x` is evaluated twice so in this case using macro will be fine. In macro call `MAX(x++, y++);`, none of the argument evaluated more than once.

Comment: @haccks That is incorrect. As Joachim says in his answer `MAX(x++, y++)` is expanded to `((x++) < (y++) ? (x++) : (y++));` and is therefore evaluated twice. The corresponding function `max(x++, y++)`, each argument is only evaluated once

Comment: @haccks Both the `x++` and the `y++` expressions are evaluated as part of the condition. Then one of either `x++` or `y++` is evaluated once again depending on the condition in the ternary expression.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; I am talking about "argument", not about expressions of  ternary operator.

Comment: @haccks But a macro is simply *expanded* to the body of the macro, there's no evaluation of the "arguments" since those a simply pasted into the expanded macro. When using a macro such as `MAX` as defined in my answer, then it's the preprocessor which handles the macro expansion, the compiler proper doesn't see the macro invocation it only sees the expanded ternary expression.

Comment: So, you are saying that the `x++` and `y++` in the expanded expression are arguments?

Comment: @haccks: No, in the original source code they are macro arguments.  After expansion they are operands, not arguments, but the coder writing `MAX(x++, y++)` shouldn't have to know what the expansion is in order to use the macro correctly.

Comment: Second problem is mitigated by `#define MUL(a, b) ((a) * (b))`

Comment: I don't think your second example is helpful for this question. As Erbureth said, you can fix that by adding some parentheses--so it's an example of using a poorly formed macro rather than being an example of using a macro where you should be using a function.

Comment: @haccks `max(x,x++)` is undefined behaviour (whether or not it is a macro) due to writing and  separately reading variable without a sequence point in between

Comment: @Carmeister I added it because it's easy to forget things like that when writing macros, and then it blows up in your face. I also added it as another push to use functions, since [inline functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline) was introduced in C99, there's really no need to use function-like macros anymore except in legacy code.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes arguments have **side effects**.

For example, the value of `i++` is `i`, but `i` is increased by 1. As a result, the value of next `i++` will be `i + 1`.

In a macro, arguments are evaluated every time it's called for, causing resulting values; In a function, the (actual) arguments are evaluated and copied to (formal) arguments inside the function, dismissing the side effects.

When inplementing a function, you don't care about side effects. However, implicit type promotion and casting may be error-prone instead.