# Using code blocks as rvalues - inside if(), for(), while()?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c11, gcc-extensions

I've noticed that `gcc` accepts code like:

```
if ( ({ int ret; /* code here */; ret }) == some_value)
    ...;

for ( i = ({ int ret; /* code here */; ret }); i < top; i++)
    ...;
```

and so on.
One can create an *anonymous codeblock* and treat it as rvalue (as long as the last statement is a variable/value).

This is useful in some situations - the particular use-case I've found is to *return* values from inline assembly statements this way. But it'd also be possible to use this to *convert* functions returning `void` but modifying memory through pointer arguments, like:

```
void myfunc(int *arg) { *arg = ...; }

if ( ({int ret; myfunc(&ret); ret; }) == 54321) { ... };
```

I've been trying to find documentation that this is *normal8 / that the *C* standard allows for this kind of thing, *poor man's lambda*.

Can anyone provide details ?

Comment: Actually ... a bit more searching, this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compund-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c

Comment: Only your vocabulary is wrong, they are used as rvalues, here.