# C error: braced-group within expression allowed only inside a function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

In C, I have a statement like this:

```
unsigned char const Alpha[6][2] = (unsigned char)({
     { 0x90f }, { 0x92c, 0x940 }, { 0x938, 0x940 }, 
     { 0x921, 0x940 }, { 0x908 }, { 0x90f, 0x92b }
     });
```

But it produces an error as `braced-group within expression allowed only inside a function`.

Can anyone suggest a remedy.

**NOTE:**`Alpha` is a global constant and so it is outside any function.

Comment: `(unsigned char)(....)` what you want here?

Comment: I want to initialize the array inside those braces as shown @Jayesh

Comment: I think It's not allowed by ANSI/ISO C nor C++ but gcc supports it.See some statement exprassion here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Comment: [possible help you can get from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compund-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c)

Comment: A cast here is required I think as the values here are too large for `unsigned char` @Jayesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a compound literal and your values are too large for an `unsigned char`, change to:

```
unsigned short int const Alpha[][2] = {
     { 0x90f }, { 0x92c, 0x940 }, { 0x938, 0x940 }, 
     { 0x921, 0x940 }, { 0x908 }, { 0x90f, 0x92b }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char const Alpha[6][2] = {
    { 0x90f & 0xFF }, { 0x92c & 0xFF , 0x940 & 0xFF }, { 0x938 & 0xFF, 0x940 & 0xFF },
    { 0x921 & 0xFF, 0x940 & 0xFF }, { 0x908 & 0xFF }, { 0x90f & 0xFF, 0x92b & 0xFF }
};
```