# variable 1 = ({statement 1;statement 2;}) construct in C

Tags: c, gcc

```
main()

{

       int a=10,b=30,c=0;

       if( c =({a+b;b-a;})) 
       {
          printf("%d",c);
       }

}
```

why the construct ({;}) is legal in C and why it returns the last statement value as the result of the expression ( why it work similar to comma operator)?

Comment: Looks like a dup of [Are compund statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compund-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not legal standard [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), but it is a very useful GCC extension, called [statement-exprs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) (a parenthesized brace compound statement ending by some expression).

<sup>IIRC, some other compilers support that extension, e.g. [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)</sup>

Statement expressions are much more useful when they contain control flow changes and side-effects, like:

```
 c = 2*({while (a>0) a--,b--; a+b;});
```

However, in your particular case, you could just use the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

```
 if (c=(a+b,b-a))
```

Since `a+b` does not have any side effect, I guess that an optimizing compiler could handle that as

```
 if (c=b-a)
```

---

GCC provides other useful [extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), notably [local labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html#Local-Labels) using `__label__` and [label as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) with computed gotos (very useful in [threaded interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) ...). I don't know exactly why they have not been standardized. I wish that they would.

Comment: `goto` is bad enough as is, we don't want to be encouraging it by allowing it to be used with a variable destination!

Comment: Sometimes computed goto is really useful (e.g. inside a threaded bytecode interpreter). Some code (e.g. bytecode interpreters like file `byterun/interp.c` of the Ocaml compiler) runs 30% faster when using computed gotos.

Answer (score 1):

```
main()
  {

   int a=10,b=30,c=0;

   if( c =({a+b;b-a;})) 
   {
      printf("%d",c);
   }

  }
```

Here,`{a+b;b-a;}` is one scope.In this you have written 2 statements.This is actually treated as

```
   {
    c=a+b;
    c=b-a;
   }
```

Initially c value is 40 because of `a+b`. Again c is modified by `b-a`. To prove this consider following three cases..

(1).

```
 if(c=({(a=a+b);;}))
   {
      printf("%d\n",c);
      printf("%d\n",a);
   }
```

Here o/p is c=40 and a=40;Because at end of scope (i.e) in last statement is dummy (;).
so,`c=a+b` is o/p.
(2)

```
   if(c=({(a=a+b);b-a;}))
   {
      printf("%d\n",c);
      printf("%d\n",a);
   }
```

Here o/p is c=-10, a=40. Because last statement is `b-a`. this value is assigned to c.
(3)     main()
        {

```
    int a=10,b=30,c=0;
    if(c=({(a=a+b);0;}))
      {
       printf("%d\n",c);
       printf("%d\n",a);
      }
     printf("%d\n",c);
    }
```

Here o/p is c=0 only.If is not executed ,Because of last statement is 0;

C follows procedure oriented.And associativity of `()` is left to right.