# Statement in C++ macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

Reading chromium code, found helpful macro for handling EINTR errno of system calls on POSIX compliant systems.
Here are the code(base/posix/eintr_wrapper.h):

```
#define HANDLE_EINTR(x) ({ \
  decltype(x) eintr_wrapper_result; \
  do { \
    eintr_wrapper_result = (x); \
  } while (eintr_wrapper_result == -1 && errno == EINTR); \
  eintr_wrapper_result; \
})
```

The question is what is the role of last statement in macro `eintr_wrapper_result;` ?
If we use commas instead of semicolons - it will be clear - to return the result of last operation(comma operator). But what is purpose in this case?

Comment: See possible duplicate: [Are compund statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238016/1708801) ... as my answer to the that question says: *last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This macro uses the [Statement-Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) GCC extension. The last expression in the inner block serves as the value for the whole, once it has been executed, much like the comma operator.

Comment: For interest, why not just use the comma operator?

Comment: @simonwo Because `do{}while()` is not an expression, and thus can't be an operand of the comma operator.