# C unknown syntax for variable declaration

Tags: c

I have just come across a piece of code that looks pretty much like this:

```
int a = ({

    int b = 10;
    b;
});

printf("%d", a);
```

I've never seen anything like this. It turns out that we can declare a variable this way. But why the language allows this? What is the concept behind it? When it can be of a good use to use such a syntax?

Comment: See [Are compund statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238016/1708801)