# GCC's statement-expressions - what's their history w.r.t. C standard adoption?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-extensions

With `gcc`, the following is a valid C statement:

```
foo ({bar(1); baz = 2;})
```

Which is equivalent to

```
bar(1);
baz = 2;
foo(2);
```

**Edited:** Here are my (hopefully more informative) questions:

- Was the ISO C standard committee/body petitioned to make these part of the C standard?
- If it was, was it before C99? Before C11? Later?
- What were the reasons given or suggested for not adopting this as part of the language?
- Is there some large pitfall or drawback to using this construct which I'm not aware of?

Comment: "Why is this not in the language standard" – because the standards committee decided so.

Comment: While I don't see a pitfall immediately, I also don't see a large benefit from using it either... The second code block to me seems clearer and more readable, so why not just use that?

Comment: Take a look at the Linux kernel code. I don't have an example at the moment, but there are things that can only be implemented as macros, and this is how you make such a macro "return" a value.

Comment: The pitfall is that it is not standard! :-)  Standards are more about minimum guarantees when porting your code; otherwise you can use whatever your compiler vendor implements

Comment: Could you please show the entire context of the code with that expression that you say compiles with `gcc`? When I try it, I get, `error: expected expression before ‘{’ token`. And is `foo` a function or a macro?

Comment: @R_Kapp: Allow "returning" values from macros, instead of using an additional macro argument as the return value.

Comment: For reference [expression statement are covered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238016/1708801) ... most likely it is not part of the standard because no one proposed it.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Rephrased my question.

Comment: You've got a syntax error there?

Comment: The question and the statement-expr feature is interesting in C (for C++, the semantics is less obvious or less intuitive, e.g. because of destructors...). I guess that the answer to *why was it not standardized* is a matter of politics and lobbying. At some time the GCC community could not afford the heavy lobbying and work.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Did it even try? What were the replies? Don't just say "oh, it's all politics and lobbying" - what were the politics involved? Did someone lobby against this?