# Are code blocks inside parenthesis in C/C++ legal and can MSCL compile it?

Tags: c++, c, cl, gcc-extensions

I have the following code:

```
int x;
x = ({ 1; 2; 3; });
printf("%d\n", x); // should be 3
```

(If you're curious why I would ever write disgusting code like that. The answer is I'm not. I'm writing a generator that outputs C code, and having such a statement will make things a lot easier.)

The code compiles and works on Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (with warnings for unused code of course) but fails with MSCL 10.0 and 14.0 (error C2059: syntax error: '{').

My question is: 1) is there a name for this kind of code(-abuse)? 2) Is it legal in any C/C++ standard? 3) Is there a way to get MSCL to accept it?

Comment: This could be a GCC [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which is a non-standard vendor extension.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. If there's no equivalent functionality in mscl, I guess I'll have to rework my generator.

Comment: What is the point of `x = 1; 2; 3; ` even with `{}` or `({})` brackets?

Comment: If you're in C++11, you could make it a lambda and immediately call it. `x = [](){ 1; 2; return 3; }();`. (I might have the syntax wrong; it's been awhile, but you get the idea)

Comment: @WeatherVane, I used that as a simple example. What I actually want is to run a bunch of arbitrary C statements and "return" a value. I was hoping I didn't have to go C++, but I guess I can do it with lambda functions.

Comment: So it's an X-Y question?

Comment: No, I asked the question I wanted to ask. Namely: can MSCL compile this kind of statement. Since it can't, I have to rework my code (turns out I can't use lambda functions since I need flow control inside the statements).

Comment: You could generate `int x; { statement; statement; x = 3; }`

Comment: Closely related to [Are compound statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238016/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know anything about MSCL part of the question since i've always used GCC. And in GCC:

1) this is called [compound statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html);

2) this is a non-standard GCC extension.

Comment: Thanks, a quick google shows that cl doesn't have a similar feature. I guess I can use lambda functions instead. Didn't want to go C++ but I guess I have to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a compound statement expression, why not use the comma operator and just write:

```
x = ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

Comment: I used that as an example, but what I actually need is something like ```({ statement; statement; 0 })``` where scoped variables might be defined.

Comment: And why not write `x = 3;`?

Comment: @Yifan: are you generating the code with the preprocessor or with your own code generator?

Comment: To be specific, I'm modifying CGEN and the hope is that I don't have to modify more than I have to.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution for MSCL if `statement`s are not expressions.  But if the value to store in `x` is constant and `x` is not used in the statements, you could of course generate: `x = 0; statement; statement;`

Comment: So right now, the code generates something like: ```x = READ_MEM(READ_REG(x))``` where I basically want to exit out when I see ```READ_REG```. I can do it with one line of modification if I'm allowed to change READ_REG to ```({ if (some_cond_on_x) break; 0; })``` otherwise, I'll have to do more work.