# What rules of C++11 standard are used to determine the type of the expression in ({ ... })

Tags: c++, c++11, expression, gcc-extensions, gcc-statement-expression

I hasn't understand what compiler does here and why it's working c++ code

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    printf( ({  // (1)
                struct some_noize_struct {
                   // there may be another code
                };
                42;
                "abc";
              }) // (2)
            );

    return 0;
}
```

Type of expression between (1) and (2) braces is const char*. After some experimens i unrerstood that type of (1)-(2)-expression determined by last part.

Here is a sample code. It works on c++11 and later.
http://cpp.sh/5tb47

My question: how it works.

Comment: It's a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). It does not work in standard C++.

Comment: BTW this can be done in standard C++11 creating a lambda and invoking it immediately: `printf( ([&]{
                struct some_noize_struct {
                   /*... */
                };
                42;
                return "abc";
              })
            );`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you. Really, msvc produces an error on this code. g++ with --Wpedantic produces warning: ISO C++ forbids braced-groups within expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat explains, the code you listed uses a GCC compiler extension to C++ (and to C), while allows for compounds statements to be used as expressions.

In your `printf()` statement, you need to provide a `const char*` or `const char* &` expression as the first argument to the function, e.g. `printf("hello")` or `printf(getenv("PATH"))`.  The extension allows the interpretation of a curly-braced block as such an expression, using the last statement in the block. The block in your case is:

```
{ 
    struct some_noize_struct { 42 };
    42;
    "abc";
}
```

which has 3 statements. The last statement is the value of the entire expression, which means that what the `printf()` sees is essentially the same as if you had typed `printf("abc")`.

This kind of code [is not standard C++ (C++11 or any another version), nor is it standard C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1238016/1593077).

I suggest you write the maintainers of the "C++ Shell" website and ask them to display the exact compilation command-line they use, and/or make sure they use `--std=c++11` to compile C++11 code - which it looks like they aren't doing.